# Etymology of "Run of Text"?

Tags: etymology

This is somewhat of a stackoverflow cross-over.

In WPF programming, there is something called a Run. It is "intended to contain a run of formatted or unformatted text". Is "run of text" a phrase that is used outside of programming?

Furthermore, what definition of 'run' is being used? Looking at m-w.com, we assumed it was most closely related to this one:
"a continuous period or series especially of things of identical or similar sort : as"

Comment: https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=run+meaning    Expand the box and check the noun part. There you will have your answers.

Comment: Why would "run of text" not be valid outside of programming?  It might mean something different, but in an appropriate context it's a perfectly meaningful phrase.

Comment: My question is if anyone uses this phrase outside of programming. A web search shows the first 30 entries are all programming related (all except this question now). I suppose it is a valid phrase, but there are many phrases that are valid without ever being put into text.